# What word is used to refer to a transvestite hater?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Suppose that someone hates transvestites or hermaphrodites. How should we call such a person? What are most appropriate words to describe exactly that kinds of intolerance?

It is in some way close to homophobia, but not exactly.

**UPD:** For my dear down voters. This is a regular question, one of many of such questions. It is nor a joke, neither I'm trying to troll. Actually, this question came up to  my mind after I had read following Kurt Vonneguts' quote:

> Here is a lesson in creative writing. First rule: Do not use semicolons. They are transvestite hermaphrodites representing absolutely nothing. All they do is show you've been to college.

Comment: Are there people that hate hermaphrodites?!?! that is straight up stupid! I live in a pretty closed minded area but never found someone that hates hermaphrodites! Must be people that think the blame should be on the parents for doing something immoral...

Comment: @BillyNair, I don't know how it goes today, but there are lot of historical evidences of hermaphrodite discrimination. They've been killed, for example, even in Ancient Greece, in a country one can hardly call homophobic - http://www.hormones.gr/149/article/article.html

Comment: I've got to go for "Not a Real Question" here. In whose universe is it meaningful to ask for a single word to describe people who hate transvestites **and** hermaphrodites? All I can think of is *"bigot"*, but that just means people who hate anyone who's *"not like us"*.

Comment: @shabunc: Your link is to a tub-thumping page whose only purpose is to show how badly hermaphrodites were treated in ancient times, when *any* significant birth-defect would probably prevent the baby from even getting past the midwife. It's got nothing to do with language or attitudes today in respect of **adults** with ambiguous gender.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - there is actually **or** in the question, not **and**

Comment: @shabunc: So, are you looking for ***two*** words? One for people who hate transvestites, and another for people who hate hermaphrodites? Or maybe ***three*** words - those two, plus another for people who hate both? Sorry, but for my money this is an unpleasant question in and of itself, **and** if any such words existed (which I doubt) I would not wish to see them promoted here.

Comment: I'm asking about two words, sorry if that confused you. Besides, I have a strong feeling that this question annoying you somehow. It sounds like you arguing, and I honestly don't know exactly why.

Comment: @shabunc: Yes, I am a bit irritated. If you wanted two different words you should have asked two different questions. Lumping them together carries implications. Would you post a single question asking what to call people who hate negroes or old people?

Comment: @FumbleFingers, will be more careful while stating questions next time, sorry. Have no intention to irritate anybody.

Comment: @shabunc: Fair enough (I've no intention of being constantly irritated, either! :)

Comment: careful the *red zone* there, @FumbleFingers. Have a smoothie :)

Comment: @BillyNair: a concept doesn't have to exist in reality before there can be a word for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Homophobe* has already been coined to mean a person having an aversion to homosexuality. And it turns out there is already a term, *gynandromorph*, for a creature of combined "male" and "female" type. One could surely refer to a person having an aversion to transsexuals or hermaphrodites as a ***gynandrophobe***.

Comment: i've combined in this question actually two questions, as @FumbleFingers mentioned. My bad, would be more careful next time. But since gynandrophobe is more non-obviuos, let this one be the answer.

Comment: From the etymology, *gynandrophobe* would be somebody who hates (or fears) both men and women.

Answer (score 13):

The closest established term is [*transphobia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transphobia), but that applies best to bigotry against transgendered individuals.  It would not be completely foreign to the case of bigotry against cross-dressing or intersexed people as you describe, though.

Comment: Phobias are not necessarily naming objects of hatred.

Comment: Agree with @DWin, -phobia is sometimes meant to include hatred, but as a component of fear. Mis- and miso- are more often used for hatred, like misogyny.

Comment: I actually came back to delete my comment after doing some further browsing, but will hold off since it would ruin the context for Beadles comment. I became convinced that there has been a shift in meanings.

Comment: @DWin: The overwhelming popular usage of *homophobia* as meaning "hatred (rooted in fear) of homosexuals" has made this objection basically purely pedantic in nature.

Comment: I came around to agreeing with you. The terms Anglophobe and Francophobe are further arguments in favor of your point.

Comment: @DWin: Oh, true, thanks.  Don't let me give the impression that I think there's anything wrong with making purely pedantic objections, though.

Comment: The term "homophobia" doesn't really follow normal rules of construction from foreign roots. It is built from Greek words meaning "same" and "fear", and so should logically mean "fear of sameness" (anti-monotony?) or maybe "fear of things the same as yourself". But in fact it was invented to mean "hatred of homosexuals". Fear is not the same as hatred. Then it is routinely applied to anyone who expresses moral disapproval of homosexuality, which is not the same as either fear or hatred: someone could, say, disapprove of conservative political ideas without hating all conservatives. Oh well.

Comment: Based on the comments here (I like @chaos's "hatred rooted in fear") I suppose it's fair to say that the meaning has shifted somewhat, but certainly has not shifted totally. E.g., agoraphobia, arachnophobia, etc. are all pretty well established as "fears" and not hatreds.  I'm just not sure if "transphobia" would be universally understood in this context.

Comment: @MarkBeadles: Yeah, no question that the popular understanding of *-phobia* hasn't totally shifted, it's just come to encompass the bigotry-oriented usage.  I don't think "transphobia" would be universally understood, no, but since it is common and usually preferred in the relevant activist communities, it's probably best to use and raise awareness of it rather than casting farther afield.

Comment: +1 @chaos, this is the only term recognized in the community (in N. America, at least). It will have emerged from the community's use and recognition of the term "homophobia," with the the suffix *phobia* combined with the prefix *trans*. That said, I know this term refers to hatred of transgendered people, but I don't know if it encompasses hatred of hermaphrodites.

Comment: @JAM: Yeah, I would consider it to be relevant mostly insofar as the T in LGBTQ somewhat brings transvestism and intersex issues under its umbrella.  So, not in a particularly high-profile or reliable way.

Comment: Transmisogyny is also a word in use, but applies exclusively to trans women.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any specific term. I think you could use the general construction "anti-hermaphrodite". That would probably be more clear than any specific term, anyway.

Comment: may be you are right. After all, nazis hated disabled persons and gipsies, but there's not specific well known words for this.